# Django: How do you take two datetime fields from a form, calculate the difference in hours, and save to a database?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-orm

In the end, I would like to have a table that has a persons name, start time, end time, and hours worked (difference between start and end times).  I am taking the start time and end times as datetimes from a form, but cannot figure out how to add the difference in hours without getting an error.  I tried just subtracting request.POST['start'] from request.POST['end'] but it gave me an error about not being allowed to substract type  unicode from unicode.

Here is what I have so far in **views.py** that is giving me errors...

```
if request.method =='POST':
    e = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.POST['end'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    s = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.POST['start'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    timediff = e-s
    workform=WorkdayForm(request.POST)
    if workform.is_valid():
        instance = workform.save(commit=False)
        instance.unit = unit
        instance.hospital = hospital
        instance.start = request.POST['start']
        instance.end = request.POST['end']
        instance.hours = timediff
        instance.system = system
        instance.save()
```

Here is the **models.py**...

```
class Workday(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
    hours = models.DateTimeField()
```

1. How do I go about saving the hours field from the start and end form inputs?
2. I wanted to use this for an sql query that would sum the hours worked in a week and join it with a table that listed info about the user (email, phone#, position)... could I use a function here instead somehow?  Also, if anyone wants to be really helpful, what would that type of query look like in djangos orm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use data from `request.POST` use data from `form.cleaned_data` to get appropriate data.

You can update your code as:

```
if request.method =='POST':
    workform=WorkdayForm(request.POST)
    if workform.is_valid():
        instance = workform.save(commit=False)
        instance.unit = unit
        instance.hospital = hospital

        instance.start = form.cleaned_data['start']
        instance.end = form.cleaned_data['end']
        timediff = instance.end - instance.start
        instance.hours = timediff.seconds/3600

        instance.system = system
        instance.save()
```

You need to change your model  to have `hours` as integer field, rather than `DateTimeField`.